# In tkinter how do I assign the entry function to a variable

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to use it in a if statment to check if the username is equal to the accepted answer. I used .get() on my ent_username to try to get the name choosen but it did not work. Is it that it never really gets entered as the username will i need to do more code with the button. Please help....

```
import tkinter
action = ""
#create new window
window = tkinter.Tk()

#name window
window.title("Basic window")

#window sized
window.geometry("250x200")

#creates label then uses ut
lbl = tkinter.Label(window, text="The game of a life time!", bg="#a1dbcd")

#pack label
lbl.pack()

#create username
lbl_username = tkinter.Label(window, text="Username", bg="#a1dbcd")
ent_username = tkinter.Entry(window)

#pack username
lbl_username.pack()
ent_username.pack()
#attempting to get the ent_username info to store
username = ent_username.get()

#configure window
window.configure(background="#a1dbcd")

#basic enter for password
lbl_password = tkinter.Label(window, text="Password", bg="#a1dbcd")
ent_password = tkinter.Entry(window)

#pack password
lbl_password.pack()
ent_password.pack()
#def to check if username is valid
def question():
    if username == "louis":
        print("you know")
    else:
        print("failed")

#will make the sign up button and will call question on click
btn = tkinter.Button(window, text="Sign up", command=lambda: question())

#pack buttons
btn.pack()

#draw window
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you are trying to `get` the contents of the Entry widget when the widget is created. And this will always be empty string. You need to move the `.get()` inside the function so it gets the value when clicking the button.

```
def question():
    username = ent_username.get() # Get value here
    if username == "louis":
        print("you know")
    else:
        print("failed")
```

Or `if ent_username.get() == "louis":`

You do have the option to use a `StringVar` but I've never found the need to use it except with OptionMenu widget

Also, a couple of side notes. When using the `command` argument, you only need `lambda` when passing in a variable, just make sure to drop the `()`.

```
btn = tkinter.Button(window, text="Sign up", command=question)
```

And a common practice is to `import tkinter as tk`. This way you are not prefixing everything with `tkinter` and instead `tk`. It just saves typing and space. So it looks like so,

```
ent_username = tk.Entry(window)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach is to associate a variable with the Entry widget. For the variable, you have to use one of the [Tkinter variables](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm), and it has to be the tkinter variable associated with that sort of widget. For the Entry widget, you need a Stringvar. See Effbot's third-party [documentation for the Entry widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm).

```
username = tkinter.StringVar()
ent_password = tkinter.Entry(window, textvariable=username)
```

In the event handler `question`, you can then access the Tkinter variable's value.

```
if username.get() == name_you_want:
    print "as expected"
```

That handler function name `question` is the correct value for the `command` argument, as Summers said:

```
btn = tkinter.Button(window, text="Sign up", command=question)
```